# Retrieve Cellset Value in SSAS\MDX

Tags: asp.net, ssas, adomd.net

Im writing SSAS MDX queries involving more than 2 axis' to retrieve a value.  Using ADOMD.NET, I can get the returned cellset and determine the value by using

```
lblTotalGrossSales.Text = CellSet.Cells(0).Value
```

Is there a way I can get the CellSet's Cell(0) Value in my MDX query, instead of relying on the data returning to ADOMD.NET?

thanks!

---

Edit 1: - Based on Daryl's comment, here's some elaboration on what Im doing.  My current query is using several axis', which is:

```
SELECT {[Term Date].[Date Calcs].[MTD]} ON 0, 
{[Sale Date].[YQMD].[DAY].&[20121115]} ON 1, 
{[Customer].[ID].[All].[A612Q4-35]} ON 2, 
{[Measures].[Loss]} ON 3 
FROM OUR_CUBE
```

If I run that query in Management Studio, I am told Results cannot be displayed for cellsets with more than two axes - which makes sense since.. you know.. there's more than 2 axes.  However, if I use ADOMD.NET to run this query in-line, and read the returning value into an ADOMD.NET cellset, I can check the value at cell "0", giving me my value... which as I understand it (im a total noob at cubes) is the value sitting where all these values intersect.

So to answer your question Daryl, what I'd love to have is the ability to have the value here returned to me, not have to read in a cell set into the calling application.  Why you may ask?  Well.. ultimately I'd love to have one query that performs several multi-axis queries to return the values.  Again.. Im VERY new to cubes and MDX, so it's possible Im going at this all wrong (Im a .NET developer by trade).

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to achieve.  You ask "Is there a way I can get the CellSet's Cell(0) Value in my MDX query" - does your mdx return the desired response and you want to organise the cellset to be more readable or do you want to change the underlying mdx query?  maybe a pseudo code example of what you hope to achieve would help

Comment: Thanks Daryl, just added more details

Comment: Thanks ewitkows, that helps.  Just to make sure we are not overly complicating the situation, are you planning on consuming all four axis or would cross joining two be sufficient? 

SELECT {[Measures].[Loss]} ON 0, 
{[Term Date].[Date Calcs].[MTD] * [Sale Date].[YQMD].[DAY].&[20121115] * [Customer].[ID].[All].[A612Q4-35]} ON 1
FROM OUR_CUBE

Comment: Nope, not using any of those 4 axis values in itself, just the value that meets where they all intersect (if that makes sense, lol)

Comment: So the above mdx (in comment) will return the data you require on 2 axis and therefore work in management studio.  If you do not require the dimensional detail, then you can move it to the slicer leaving only the measure.

Comment: Hi, so, it's not possible to retrieve a value from 4 dimensions with C# code?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your query to return two axis;

`SELECT {[Measures].[Loss]} ON 0, {[Term Date].[Date Calcs].[MTD] * [Sale Date].[YQMD].[DAY].&[20121115] * [Customer].[ID].[All].[A612Q4-35]} ON 1 FROM OUR_CUBE`

and then try the following to access the cellset;

```
 string connectionString =  "Data Source=localhost;Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2012";
        //Create a new string builder to store the results
        System.Text.StringBuilder result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection(connectionString);
        //Connect to the local serverusing (AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=localhost;"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            //Create a command, using this connection
            AdomdCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT {  [Measures].[Unit Price]  } ON COLUMNS , {[Product].[Color].[Color].MEMBERS-[Product].[Color].[]} * [Product].[Model Name].[Model Name]ON ROWS FROM [Adventure Works] ;";

            //Execute the query, returning a cellset
            CellSet cs = cmd.ExecuteCellSet();

            //Output the column captions from the first axis//Note that this procedure assumes a single member exists per column.
            result.Append("\t\t\t");

            TupleCollection tuplesOnColumns = cs.Axes[0].Set.Tuples;

            foreach (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.Tuple column in tuplesOnColumns)
            {
                result.Append(column.Members[0].Caption + "\t");

            }
            result.AppendLine();

            //Output the row captions from the second axis and cell data//Note that this procedure assumes a two-dimensional cellset
            TupleCollection tuplesOnRows = cs.Axes[1].Set.Tuples;
            for (int row = 0; row < tuplesOnRows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int members = 0; members < tuplesOnRows[row].Members.Count; members++ )
                {
                    result.Append(tuplesOnRows[row].Members[members].Caption + "\t");
                }


                for (int col = 0; col < tuplesOnColumns.Count; col++)
                {
                    result.Append(cs.Cells[col, row].FormattedValue + "\t");
                }
                result.AppendLine();
            }
            conn.Close();

            TextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
        } // using connection
```

[Source : Retrieving Data Using the CellSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123476%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

This is fine upto select on columns and on Rows. It will be helpful analyze how to traverse sub select queries from main query.